# "Move focus to next window" short cut toggling window order if I interact with a window

Tags: mail.app, shortcut, window-manager

There is a very convenient keyboard short cut to go through all windows opened by the same application. For me (but it is not the same for everyone) it is Ctrl < to flip through the window in one order, and Ctrl > to flip backwards. So far so good.

The bug (I can't think how it can be a feature), is that the order of windows is toggled as soon as I interact with one window. Let me explain with an example

- I open Mac mail, I create (Cmd N) say 3 new windows with topic Draft 1, Draft 2, Draft 3. If I use Ctrl < it flips through Draft 2 Draft 1 Draft 3 etc... and Ctrl > flips in forward order
- now I'm on Draft 2, I modify the title to be Super Draft 2. Now Ctrl < flips in forward order ! Draft 3 Draft 1 Super Draft 2 etc... (and Ctrl > backward) !
- I can reproduce the bug with safari windows (not tab, really separate windows), so it looks like it is not specific to Mail

This is very inconvenient : I can have a dozen draft email windows opened, and I'd like to go through them systematically and possibly modify some. This bug forces me to toggle between Ctrl < and Ctrl > semi randomly in order to be sure I cycle through all windows.

I'm on Mac Book Pro with Catalina 10.15.4 but this behavior is there since I learned to use the toggle window shortcut, one or two years ago.